# Update Database with Migrations CLI on VS for Mac (DotNet Core 2)

Tags: database, migration, .net-core, command-line-interface, visual-studio-mac

I created the Models of my database on VS for Mac and used terminal for create migrations:

```
dotnet ef migrations add IntitialMigration
```

Then, I updated my database:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

But after I changed my Models and I created another migration:

```
dotnet ef migrations add SecondMigration
```

And tried to update the database:

```
dotnet ef database update SecondMigration
```

I received the following error:

> There is already an object named 'Emails' in the database.

I've searched and I found a probably solution:

```
Add-Migration SecondMigration -IgnoreChanges
```

But this only works at PMC on Windows. I'm using VS for Mac and all the commands are typed on Terminal. Does anybody know how to update a database using Migrations after change the Models?

Comment: Please are you find the solution for your the above issue on the vs for mac with asp.net core ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems that on VS 2017 for Windows, when you add a Migration, it is automatically added on the solution. But, on VS for Mac, that doesn't happen.  You need to manually add the each new migration to the solution. I created the InitialMigration migration and update it to the database. For some reason I don't know why, I removed the migration from the solution and I created the new SecondMigration migration. That's the reason that all the tables that were on InitialMigration were on SecondMigration too.

Answer (score 0):

If you just run update database it will also try to update with previous migration. (which is why its complains about adding whats already there). You can run an update just for one single migration by adding the name of the migration you want to run after the command.